# Compare 1 independent vs many dependent variables using plotly in a horizontal plot

Tags: python, plotly

I'm looking for the answer to the same question as on [Compare 1 independent vs many dependent variables using seaborn pairplot in an horizontal plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966494/compare-1-independent-vs-many-dependent-variables-using-seaborn-pairplot-in-an-h) but using Plotly.

I've checked https://plotly.com/python/splom/ but doesn't seem like they have 'y_vars' or 'x_vars' arguments.

Any helped welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do a "pair plot" in plolty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823919/is-it-possible-to-do-a-pair-plot-in-plolty)

Comment: Nope, My question is about selecting why columns go in X and which goes in Y.